# TPL Dataflow and console application doesn't terminate the application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've a console application that should be called in a batch and compress huge files, I wanted to use DataFlow and everything works fine except for the completion

Consider please the following code

```
public static void CompressFiles(string folder)
{
    var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<FileInfo>();

    bufferBlock.LinkTo(Target(), new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true});
        var files = GetFilesFromFolder(folder);

        Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
        {
            bufferBlock.Post(file);
        });

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
        {
            CreateFileT(file.FullName);
        });

        sw.Stop();

       // Task.WaitAll(bufferBlock.Completion);

        bufferBlock.Completion.Wait();
        string tempoImpiegato =
            $"[Generatore PDZ] : tempo impiegato per la generazione di {files.Length} pdz : {sw.Elapsed}";

        LogManager.GetLogger("normal").Info(tempoImpiegato);
    }
```

and the compression ActionBlock that's

```
private static ActionBlock<FileInfo> Target()
    {
        return new ActionBlock<FileInfo>(file =>
        {
            FileInfo bolFileName = new FileInfo(file.FullName.Replace($"{ApplicationHelper.FileExtensionPdf}", $"{ApplicationHelper.FileExtensionBOL}"));
            FileInfo zipFileName = new FileInfo(file.FullName.Replace($"{ApplicationHelper.FileExtensionPdf}", $"{ApplicationHelper.FileExtensionPdz}"));

            if (!File.Exists(file.FullName) || !File.Exists(bolFileName.FullName))
            {
                string s = $"File {file.FullName} o {bolFileName.FullName} non esistenti o inaccessibili";
                Log.Warning(s);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(zipFileName.OpenWrite()))
                    {
                        s.SetLevel(9);

                        ZipEntry entry1 = new ZipEntry(file.Name);
                        ZipEntry entry2 = new ZipEntry(bolFileName.Name);

                        entry1.Size = file.Length;
                        entry2.Size = bolFileName.Length;

                        byte[] buffer = ReadBytesFromFileInfo(file);
                        byte[] bufferBol = ReadBytesFromFileInfo(bolFileName);

                        s.PutNextEntry(entry1);
                        s.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
                        s.PutNextEntry(entry2);
                        s.Write(bufferBol, 0, bufferBol.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(ex, "");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Using `bufferBlock.Completion.Wait()` blocks the program without going further...what am I doing wrong since I've set `PropagateCompletion` to true and the `Target()` works (it generates the files)

Comment: -You don't really need a `BufferBlock`, you can post directly to the `ActionBlock`.
-There's probably no use in posting to the block inside a parallel for.
-You should probably wait for the block's completion synchronously using async-await instead of blocking (i.e. `await bufferBlock.Completion`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are waiting for completion but you are not signaling completion. The `BufferBlock` is waiting for more items, it doesn't know you aren't going to post any more items into it.

To signal completion you need to call `Complete` before waiting for completion:

```
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```